# Триггер функции для разных елементов под общим классом

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
foreach($articles as $article)
{
    <input class="a">
}
```

В результате на странице есть несколько `input`.
Есть функция:

```
$(".а").on("rating.change", function (event, value) {
    var voted = false;
    @if (Session::has('/vote/'.$article->id))
        voted = true;
    @endif
    if (voted)
        alert("Ошибка");
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/vote/{{$article->id}}',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'rating': value, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        });
    }
});
```

Но функция работает везде по одному маршруту (`/vote/1` к примеру), как ее изменить, чтобы срабатывала для каждого `id`?

```
$(".а").each(function() {...});
```

не помогло

> p.s. использую http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте `data` атрибуты к примеру, в цикле дайте им атрибуты `id` и `voted`:

```
foreach($articles as $article)
{
    <input class="a" data-id = "<?php echo $article->id; ?>" data-voted="<?php echo (Session::has('/vote/'.$article->id) ? 'true' : 'false') ?>">
}
```

Если используeтe Blade можете на нем переписать вставку, и потом в js измените пару строк:

```
$(".а").on("rating.change", function (event, value) {  

    if ($(this).data('voted') == 'true')
        alert("Ошибка");
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/vote/' + $(this).data('id'),
            method: 'POST',
            data: {'rating': value, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        });
    }
});
```

По идее должно отработать если `$(this)` это объект инпута